# How to call or trigger a function in-between two microservices using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, microservices

I'm facing an issue in microservices with nodeJS. I have to create a common service for notifications to send notifications from various services. I don't know how to call a functions in-between two microservice or two nodes.

**Example:**

**Microservice1 -**

```
app.post('/addUser',(req,res)=>{
    Microservice3.sendNotification();
})
```

**Microservice2 -**

```
app.post('/addRank',(req,res)=>{
    Microservice3.sendNotification();
})
```

**Microservice3 -**

```
function sendNotification(){
   socket.emit('notification',data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest solution would be to attach sendNotification() function to an api endpoint and call the api from Microservices 1 and 2 and send data with it.

Comment: Thanks @Mahad Ansar, I'm just doing like that.